# IPv6 problems with vxlan and tailscale

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I installed tailscale and I have a tailscale0 interface. Now, I want to create a vxlan interface. If I choose eth0 as the interface the VTEP communicates through, things work in both ipv4 and ipv6. For example, for ipv6, this works:

```
sudo ip link add vxlan-testing type vxlan id 10 dstport 4789 dev eth0
sudo ip addr add 2001:abcc:99::/128 dev vxlan-testing
```

If I choose the tailscale0 interface instead, things work for ipv4:

```
sudo ip link add vxlan-testing type vxlan id 10 dstport 4789 dev tailscale0
sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.12/32 dev vxlan-testing
```

But they don't for ipv6:

```
sudo ip link add vxlan-testing type vxlan id 10 dstport 4789 dev tailscale0
sudo ip addr add 2001:abcc:99::/128 dev vxlan-testing
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Why do I get that `RTNETLINK` message only in the ipv6 case? Unfortunately, the error does not help much. This is my tailscale interface:

```
44: tailscale0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/none  promiscuity 0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 65535 
    tun type tun pi on vnet_hdr off persist off addrgenmode random numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

The tailscale interface has ipv4 (`100.126.X.X/32`) and ipv6 addresses (`fd7a:115c:a1e0:ab12:4843:X:X:X/128`; `fe80::e3fa:fe1f:X:X/64`)